# ¿Cómo calcular el promedio dentro de consulta MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo una consulta y una subconsulta en la que muestro dos columnas, una con el número de temas totales y otra con el número de temas vistos por dicho usuario, lo que quiero también es otra columna con el resultado en porcentaje utilizando las 2 columnas mencionadas, la consulta:

```
SELECT inscritos.usuario_id, inscritos.curso_id, concat(usuarios1.nombre, " ", usuarios1.ap_p)as usuario, cursos.curso_nombre, vtemastotal.total_temas,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) 
     FROM avance 
     WHERE avance.usuario_id=inscritos.usuario_id 
     AND avance.curso_id=inscritos.curso_id)as vistos
FROM inscritos
LEFT JOIN cursos ON cursos.curso_id=inscritos.curso_id
LEFT JOIN usuarios1 ON usuarios1.id=inscritos.usuario_id
JOIN vtemastotal on vtemastotal.curso_id=inscritos.curso_id 
ORDER BY inscritos.usuario_id
```

Los datos obtenidos:

```
usuario_id  curso_id    usuario            curso_nombre total_temas vistos  
      2         4       Estudiante A_P         Test          7        3
      2         5       Estudiante A_P         Excel         2        2
      3         4       Estudiante No. 2 AP    Test          7        7
      3         5       Estudiante No. 2 AP    Excel         2        0
      3         6       Estudiante No. 2 AP    Word          1        0
```

Esto es lo que me hace falta:

```
usuario_id  curso_id    usuario            curso_nombre total_temas vistos  porcen  
      2         4       Estudiante A_P         Test          7        3      42.8
      2         5       Estudiante A_P         Excel         2        2      100
      3         4       Estudiante No. 2 AP    Test          7        7      100
      3         5       Estudiante No. 2 AP    Excel         2        0       0
      3         6       Estudiante No. 2 AP    Word          1        0       0
```

Comment: podrias agregar:
(vistos/total_temas*100) as porcentaje

Comment: Desconoce la columna vistos :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La respuesta rápida es repitiendo la subconsulta.

```
SELECT inscritos.usuario_id, inscritos.curso_id, concat(usuarios1.nombre, " ", usuarios1.ap_p)as usuario, cursos.curso_nombre, vtemastotal.total_temas,
    (SELECT COUNT(*)
     FROM avance
     WHERE avance.usuario_id=inscritos.usuario_id
     AND avance.curso_id=inscritos.curso_id) as vistos,
     (SELECT COUNT(*)
     FROM avance
     WHERE avance.usuario_id=inscritos.usuario_id
     AND avance.curso_id=inscritos.curso_id) / vtemastotal.total_temas * 100 as porcen
FROM inscritos
LEFT JOIN cursos ON cursos.curso_id=inscritos.curso_id
LEFT JOIN usuarios1 ON usuarios1.id=inscritos.usuario_id
JOIN vtemastotal on vtemastotal.curso_id=inscritos.curso_id 
ORDER BY inscritos.usuario_id
```

Comment: Así, sí funcionó, gracias!